# Can we reduce the length of suspension for this user?

Tags: discussion, bounty

There's 15 hours left on a bountied question, but the person who offered the bounty is suspended and his suspension doesn't expire until about 2 days, meaning he may not be able to award the bounty himself?

That's not fair: It's a 300 point bounty. The largest bounty ever offered on QCSE. Let him award it himself rather than having it just automatically going to someone (looks like it's going to be Martin) whose answer the author might not have liked.

Whether you've suspended him for 7 days or 6.5 days doesn't make a difference to the community but not letting him award that bounty himself will leave a sour taste in a lot of people's mouths.

Answer (score 3):

For the record: that was not the intention of the moderators.

In any sense.

But rest assured that suspension was necessary. [We can't explain why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293213/why-we-dont-keep-public-records-of-suspensions), but you probably saw at least some of the comments on that question and some of this user's behavior that lead to our decision. I'm afraid this is simply part of the consequence at this point. Half the bounty will be automatically awarded by the system to the highest voted answer posted while the bounty was active.*

If you'd like to escalate this issue, please feel free to talk to the community mods or ping me in chat. I really do understand what you're saying, but this is the way it is.

See also [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100050/suspended-user-cannot-award-bounty). If the author cares that much, they can request that the CMs award the bounty for them, but they may not considering that the user was punished for a reason, and that it's generally kind of odd to accommodate that sort of behavior, whether by shortening the suspension or by another workaround.

---

*There's actually a little more to it than that in general; see [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) for more details. In this case, however, what I said is effectively true.